# StyleFrame can't write unicode headlines python

Tags: python, pandas, styleframe

While using the StyleFrame package for styling pandas DataFrame with openpyxl i got the following Exception.

When i try this code with an english title it works as i excepted.

```
   self.sf.set_column_width(columns=u'שם הלקוח', width=35)
   File "/Users/talperetz/.virtualenvs/natan-report/lib/python2.7/site-packages/StyleFrame/style_frame.py", line 259, in set_column_width
     raise TypeError("column must be an index, column letter or column name")
    TypeError: column must be an index, column letter or column name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using version `0.0.7` or earlier. Version `0.0.8` has an improved support in unicode so try to upgrade.